# How to fix "Unexpected section title"?

Tags: python-sphinx, docstring, sections, autodoc, sphinx-napoleon

This docstring:

```py
"""
Returns
-------
out: int
    Output.


Bad title
---------
Text.
"""
```

produces:

```
C:\module.py:docstring of my_pkg.module.func:5: CRITICAL: Unexpected section title.

Bad title
---------
```

Can I make it respect `Bad title`, or at least suppress the warning? I'm not using `numpydoc` or Napoleon, only

```py
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']
```

The two related questions with shared "Unexpected etc" don't help.

---

#### MRE

Built with `sphinx-build -a -E . build`. For convenience, here's [sphinx-dummy-min.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ruEYiu_GkL3rulaLZQ551_Muv9KP6iNh/view?usp=sharing).

`sphinx-dummy-min/docs/conf.py`

```py
import sys, pathlib

sys.path.insert(0, str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent))

project = 'dummy-module'
release = version = '0.1.0'
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']
exclude_patterns = ['build']
```

`sphinx-dummy-min/docs/dummy_module.rst`

```
sphinx-dummy-min package
========================

Submodules
----------

dummy_module.dumdum module
--------------------------

.. automodule:: dummy_module.dumdum
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:


Module contents
---------------

.. automodule:: dummy_module
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

`sphinx-dummy-min/docs/index.rst`

```
Welcome to dummy-module-min's documentation!
============================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Galleries:

   API reference <dummy_module>


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

`sphinx-dummy-min/dummy_module/__init__.py`

`sphinx-dummy-min/dummy_module/dumdum.py`

```py
def bark():
    """
    Returns
    -------
    out: str
        "Bark".


    Bad title
    ---------
    Body.
    """
```

Comment: Are you using Napoleon? "Returns" is a supported section heading. "Bad title" is not. https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html#docstring-sections.

Comment: @bad_coder "I'm not using numpydoc, **just sphinx-build with 'sphinx.ext.autodoc'.**" I never mentioned Napoleon, it was your assumption.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon then I'm not going to explain why your code implies napoleon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arbitrary titles can be supported via `'sphinx.ext.napoleon'`'s [`napoleon_custom_sections`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html#confval-napoleon_custom_sections) in `conf.py`:

```py
napoleon_custom_sections = ['Bad title']
```

This can be automated by iterating all `.py` in the package and finding `----` in docstrings - my approach below.

Note, nested titles will also generate the warning - e.g.

```
Parameters
----------
param: str
    This is a param.

    Extended description
    --------------------
    This is a parameter.
```

but that's fair enough.

---

#### Auto custom sections

```py
from pathlib import Path

def scrape_titles_in_folder(_dir):
    def scrape_titles_in_file(p):
        with open(p, 'r') as f:
            txt_lines = f.readlines()
        titles = []
        inside_of_docstring = False
        for i, line in enumerate(txt_lines):
            if '"""' in line:
                inside_of_docstring = not inside_of_docstring
            # '---' or shorter is prone to false positives
            subsection_symbols = ('-', '^')  # can add more

            if (inside_of_docstring and
                # `3` or less is prone to false positives (e.g. '-')
                    any(s * 4 in line for s in subsection_symbols)):
                contender = txt_lines[i - 1].strip(' \n')
                if contender != '':  # can appear for some reason
                    titles.append(contender)

            # e.g. """Docstring."""
            if line.count('"""') == 2:
                inside_of_docstring = not inside_of_docstring
        return titles

    all_titles = []
    for p in _dir.iterdir():
        if p.suffix == '.py':
            all_titles.extend(scrape_titles_in_file(p))
        elif p.is_dir():
            all_titles.extend(scrape_titles_in_folder(p))
    return list(set(all_titles))  # unique only

module_dir = Path(Path(__file__).parent.parent, 'dummy_module')
section_titles = scrape_titles_in_folder(module_dir)

napoleon_custom_sections = section_titles
```